# How to generate <form:input> tags dynamically from JS?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to generate two type of fields, with a specific tags `<form:input>` and `<form:hidden>` dynamically from JS.
The first one `<form:input>` should be an input field the second, must be hidden. 
The problem is that `<form:input>` is not recognized as an input and it's not shown at all. But it can be seen from the page source code.

```
if (bank != null) {
    var fields = bank.additionalFields;
    var additionalRows = document.getElementById("additionalRows");
    for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

        //from here generates jsp inputs:
        //1 - <form:input>
        //2 - <form:hidden>  for each element from fields

        var formInput = document.createElement("form:input");
        var formHidden = document.createElement("form:hidden");

        formInput.setAttribute("path", "paymentInfo.fields[" + i + "].value");
        formHidden.setAttribute("path", "paymentInfo.fields[" + i + "].id");

        formInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
        formHidden.setAttribute("type", "text");

        formInput.setAttribute("value", "");
        formHidden.setAttribute("value", fields[i].id);

        additionalRows.appendChild(formInput);
        additionalRows.appendChild(formHidden);
    }
}
```

Other `<form:input>` fields generated from JSP are appearing properly on the page.
Link to the generated page source code >> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/106355152/form_input.PNG
How can it be resolved?

Comment: It appears you are trying to generate server side-code with client-side code.

Comment: You need to insert normal input tags on the client side - not jsp ones

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do likely cannot be done. `<form:input>` and `<form:hidden>` appear to be server side tags - this is why they are only working from the java end.

You can generate regular  and  tags using javascript in a way similar to your current approach:

```
    var formInput = document.createElement("input");
    var formHidden = document.createElement("input");

    formInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    formHidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
```

and then append them to your form.

Comment: wouldn't formHidden also be `document.createElement("input");`

Comment: Yes, but later I collect all the data inserted by user  to `<form:input>` in single method `selectMethodForm` that runs through all `<form:form modelAttribute="selectMethodForm" id="bankFormId">`

Comment: @user2595541 If you need to process the form data further, you will either need to post it to your server and handle it that way, or change your approach to generating these tags. You may want to look into "dynamic generation of JSP elements". As it stands, you cannot mix browser/client(Javascript) and server (JSP) code in this way.